# How Sodium Nitrite Interacts with Air and Humidity

Tags: chemical-potential

What happens to integrity of sodium nitrite (NaNo², CAS: 7632-00-0) of AR grade when it gets exposed to air?

If container has been opened and chemical has been exposed to air for a few minutes and then closed again, it's integrity keeps getting affected? Is purity affected as well?

If air happens to contain humidity, does it potentiate the effect on chemical's integrity?

Does this type of chemical expire and how long can it be stored unopened? What happens after chemical has reached its expiration?

How long can it be stored after being exposed to air and then closed in it's container for later projects? Additionally, as far as integrity and purity are concerned, is it reliable for repeated use for important project?

Thanks

Comment: "Sodium nitrite comes in the form of white or off-white powdery crystals that gradually oxidize to sodium nitrate. It is hygroscopic and easily soluble in water (making the water solution alkaline)" according to this source https://www.ube.com/contents/en/chemical/industrial_chemicals/sodium_nitrite.html. Clearly it should be stored in a dry cabinet and exposed to the air as little as possible.

Comment: What is $\ce{NaNO^2}$?